# Kusto - How to put results into another table in another cluster?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Suppose I have a table, I run a query like below :-

let data = orders | where zip == "11413" | project timestamp, name, amount  ;
inject data into newOrdersInfoTable in another cluster // ==> How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. If it is a manual task and with not too much data you can simply do something like this in the **target** cluster:

```
.set-or-append TargetTable <| cluster("put here the source cluster url").database("put here the source database").orders 
| where zip == "11413" | project timestamp, name, amount
```

Note that if the dataset is larger you can use the "async" flavor of [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query). If the data size is bigger then you should consider exporting the data and importing it to the other cluster.